# TypeScript Express Restful API don't register routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have created simple REST API for my Application.
At the beginning API was written in JavaScript and everything works fine.
I decided to switch to TypeScript. With couple changes related to types, adding ts config file, Express-TypeScript server was running. However when I tested the API with http client, request hang as if no route was registered by Express. I tried to diagnose the problem and I have defined routes directly in `index.ts` file and works properly. Seems like there is some problem with `createServer.ts` helper function. If you have any idea what might be wrong I'll be glad to hear explanation, thank you in advance!

`createServer.ts`

```js
import express, { Application } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import validateToken from "../middleware/validateToken";
import cors from "cors";

// routes
import user from "../routes/user";
import note from "../routes/note";
import speechRecognition from "../routes/speechRecognition";

cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5000", credentials: true });

function createServer(): Application {
  const app = express();

  app.use(cors);
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  app.use(
    validateToken.unless({
      path: [
        { url: "/user", method: "POST" },
        "/user/authenticate",
        "/user/refresh-token",
      ],
    })
  );

  app.use("/user", user);
  app.use("/note", note);
  app.use("/api", speechRecognition);

  return app;
}

export default createServer;
```

`index.ts`

```js
import { path } from "app-root-path";
import { Port } from "./types/Port";
import { Application } from "express";

// env
import { config } from "dotenv";
config({ path: `${path}/../.env` });

// express
import createServer from "../server/utils/createServer";

// db connection
import { dbConnection } from "../server/db/connection";

dbConnection(process.env.DB_URI as string);

const app: Application = createServer();

const port: Port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`));
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

`package.json script`

```json
"server": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `cors` middleware correctly:

```
function createServer(): Application {
  const app = express();

  app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5000", credentials: true }));
  …
}
```